# Move entire UIScrollView when scrolling. When at top, start scrolling normally

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview, or actually a UIWebView, which is initially positioned 320px from the top of its parent view.

When the user starts scrolling, I want the entire UIWebView to follow the movement upwards until it reaches the top, then the webview should start scrolling as normal. I want this to happen in the same finger movement. (That is, the user should not need to lift the finger).

I have implemented this using a UIPanGestureRecognizer on top of the UIWebView (see code below). The gesture handler moves the UIWebView and constantly resets the scrollview's contentOffset to 0. It works, but the performance is bad, especially if the webview contains a heavy page. I guess it is the scroll and reset of the webview that makes the rendering heavy. My solution kind of smells bad and I assume there must be a better way?

**Do you know any better solution to achieve what I'm trying to do?**

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *webViewScrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *webViewTopMarginConstraint;
@end

@implementation ViewController {
    BOOL gestureEnabled;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    gestureEnabled = YES;

    // Initially put the webview 320 px down on the topview
    self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.webViewTopMarginConstraint.constant = 320.0;

    // SET UP GESTURE RECOGNIZER
    _panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesturesForWebview:)];
    _panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    _panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    _panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRecognizer];

    // Get hold of the webviews scrollview
    for (UIView* subView in self.webView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            _webViewScrollView = (UIScrollView *)subView;
        }
    }

    // Load a web page in the webview
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.macrumors.com"]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)handlePanGesturesForWebview:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGFloat transY = [gesture translationInView:self.view].y; //transY will be negative by the number of pixels panned when panning upwards
        if (gestureEnabled) {
            // Move the whole webview according to gesture movement upwards
            // todo Handle scrolling in the opposite direction
            self.webViewTopMarginConstraint.constant = 320 + transY;
            if (self.webViewTopMarginConstraint.constant <= 0.0) {
                // The webview is at the top, disable the gesture recognizer
                gestureEnabled = NO;
                self.webViewTopMarginConstraint.constant = 0.0;
                self.panGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
            }
            // "Rewind" the web scrolling
            CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
            [self.webViewScrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark UIGestureRecognizerDelegate impl
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

**EDIT: Using insets as @JPHribovsek suggests in the accepted answer works perfectly. The code also became simpler. You can have a look at the solution here:** http://gist.github.com/melke/8684172

Comment: before looking at answering the actual question, did you look in other ways of achieving the visual effect you want without "moving the scrollview, then scroll, in one movement"? Have you looked at things like insets/offsets, to maybe achieve a similar effect, without having to move the scrollview around?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't try insets, but don't you think it would have the same "rerendering" effect? I would still need to keep setting the contentOffset to zero, to sort of reset the UIWebView scrolling. Ideally, I would like to prevent the webview scrolling before it happens, but I can't disable scrolling entirely, because then I wouldn't be able to pick the scrolling up again in the same finger movement.

Comment: So basically you are looking for a "parallax" feature?

Comment: @WrightsCS Parallax? Can you elaborate? What I didn't mention was that I initially have another view in the 320px space above the webview. Besides from moving the webview I also move away the other view out of screen, which to the user looks like both the webview and the other view is part of the same scrollview. When the webview reaches the top of screen it sticks, so the webview takes up the entire screen and starts scrolling normally

Comment: See some examples here: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=Parallax

Comment: Thank you! Using insets as @JPHribovsek suggests in the accepted answer works perfectly. The code also became simpler. You can have a look at the solution here: https://gist.github.com/melke/8684172

Comment: Note, you are declaring the delegate property as strong in the code on your repo, which is probably creating a retain cycle in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do more simply, without moving the scrollview, is to set a content inset

```
CGFloat top = 320.0;     
self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Note that you would need your deployment target to be iOS5+ to grab the scrollview like this, instead of looping through subviews like you did.

So overall your `viewDidLoad` method would be much simpler, and no need for gesture recognizer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat top = 320.0;     
    self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    self.webview.scrollView.delegate = self;
    // Load a web page in the webview
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.macrumors.com"]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Also, based on one of your comment from your original post, it looks like you were also moving another view along with the scrollview.
In that case you will want to track the scrolling through the scrollview delegate, and move that other view accordingly. Depending on the content of that other view (if it's just an imageView banner type thing for example), I would personally find it more elegant to resize/crop that other view rather than moving it out of the screen; but that would have to be another question I guess.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    //here whatever code you use to set that other view frame position
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Do I change the inset value in the gesture handler? How do I prevent the scrolling inside the webview (before it reaches the top) using this solution?

Comment: Either I am misunderstanding what you're trying to do, or you're complicating the issue. But, with what I understand, there is no gesture handler needed. And the scrollview doesn't move. You would start the scrollview frame 320 pix higher, and the first 320 pixels of the scrollview would initially be blank (the inset), when scrolling, that blank space would be occupied by the content. I believe this is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I might be wrong because I know that I am not technically answering what you're asking (which is how do I move a scrollview to the top, then move the content when no room to move the scrollview) ; I am answering the question: how do I display a top margin inside my webview; cause I believe that is what you're trying to achieve by having the scrollview lower initially then moving up. There might be another rationale as to why you would want to move the scrollview itself, but it sounds like you're trying to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut

Comment: I also just saw your comment about moving another view along the scrolling, you can achieve that by tracking the scrolling, and move that other view accordingly

Comment: AHA! You mean that the inset is actually consumed first? It is not a fixed margin? That looks like a great solution. I will try that tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: yeah, the inset is what's set by default on tableviews in iOS7 for example, you know, when using a semi translucent navigation bar. the inset makes the content start below the navbar, but as you scroll, the content goes underneath the bar. But the tableview/scrollview does not actually move